# link data from mysql via php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to have a combo box that shows the list of school years. Once I select a school year, the list of classes that the user (teacher) is handling will display below it. on the list of classes, the user can click a specific class and then the list of students enrolled in the class will be displayed.
I have tried it by using php and html, but I don't know how to make the list of classes clickable to display the names of the students. :(

I can't attach screen shots yet since I'm new here.

Comment: post what you've tried. and where it failed.

Comment: post your code here. as far as i understand you need ajax to load these dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to do javascript event listening so that when the first drop down list changes or is clicked, you can make an ajax post request to get the second list.

Here is a simple JSFiddle to demonstrate what I mean. 
http://jsfiddle.net/v3nct/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#SelectList").change(function() {
       alert("I changed!");

        //here is where you do the ajax post to populate the second list
    });

});
```